# Здравствуйте! Хочу поработать с pdf файлом, но пишет что версия слишком новая, что делать?

Tags: python, файлы, pdf

```
from pathlib import Path
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader

pdf_path = (
    Path.home()
    / "Desktop"
    / "Бот клиенты"
    / "Ренат"
    / "DHLeMailShip_PDFClient_RU_050005.pdf"
)
pdf = PdfFileReader(str(pdf_path))
print(pdf.getNumPages())
print(pdf.documentInfo)
page = pdf.getPage(0)
print(page.extractText())
```

Ошибка

> The document you are trying to load requires Adobe Reader 8 or higher.
> You may not have the Adobe Reader installed or your
> viewing environment may not be properly configured to use  Adobe
> Reader.

Comment: А есть трасса стека? Непонятно в каком именно месте ошибка. Посмотрел в репозиторий библиотеки и не нашел место ошибки: https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2/blob/18a2627adac13124d4122c8b92aaa863ccfb8c29/PyPDF2/pdf.py#L1750 . Как вариант, последуйте рекомендации ошибки и поставьте Adobe Reader 8 или выше

Comment: Да, судя по всему надо просто поставить AR8

Comment: так, он в ошибке говорит что открыть сможет только с помощью Adobe, а как это сделать с помощью python?